# Is it idiomatic having non-interfaces called like "*er"

Tags: go

The ["Effective Go"](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface-names) states:

> By convention, one-method interfaces are named by the method name plus
>   an -er suffix or similar modification to construct an agent noun:
>   `Reader`, `Writer`, `Formatter`, `CloseNotifier` etc.

`bufio.io` package contains this:

```
// Reader implements buffering for an io.Reader object.
type Reader struct {
    buf          []byte
    rd           io.Reader
    r, w         int
    err          error
    lastByte     int
    lastRuneSize int
}
```

Is it idiomatic having structs named like "*er"? Especially in this case it's a `struct` with the same name as `io.Reader` which is an interface.

Comment: I've never read anything suggesting that `struct`s with one method should be named ending with `-er`. Maybe in the case with the `bufio.io` package the name was the right choice because it was simple and made sense... but I don't think generally it is required.

Comment: I personally think it will be confusing. btw there is a buffering reader in the stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in Effective Go or the specs then it's a matter of opinion really, I'd say it's fine as long as it makes sense.

Using `bufio.Reader` or `bytes.Reader` as an example, they make perfect sense to be named that way.

Answer (score 2):

The comment [`type bufio.Reader struct`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader) are important:

// `Reader` implements buffering for an `io.Reader` object.

The [bufio packages adds](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/):

> It **wraps** an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) or [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) object, **creating another object (`Reader` or `Writer`)** that also implements the interface but provides buffering and some help for textual I/O.

Since `bufio.Reader` isn't there to add any new service, but only to implements an `io.Reader` in a buffered way, it makes sense to keep the name and just implement the functions: a `struct` is enough.

For the user's point of view, it is a `Reader` that he/she can uses wherever an io.Reader is required.